# "cannot assign to" while assigning to a structure member

Tags: go

The following program fails to compile with "cannot assign to f1().ID" error.

```
package main

type Employee struct {                                                                                                                                                                         
    ID        int 
    Name      string
}

func main() {
    f1().ID = 11     // causes "cannot assign to f1().ID" error
    f2().ID = 22
}

func f1() Employee {
    return Employee{1, "Dilbert 1"}
}

func f2() *Employee {
    return &Employee{2, "Dilbert 2"}
}
```

Since f1() is returning a Employee variable, why assignment to its member is not allowed?  The same works f1()'s return value is assigned to a  variable and its member is assigned a value  as follows:

```
v := f1()
v.ID = 10   // This works
```

Comment: It's not allowed because it doesn't make sense to modify a value which is never assigned (specifically, return values from functions are not addressable)

Comment: To help you answer your own question: what do you think the impact of either of the lines in `main` would be? What do you expect them to actually *do*?

Comment: Why all the downvotes here? This seems like a perfectly fine beginner question... ?

Comment: I was trying to understand the rationale behind that while reading D&K (p. 100).  I got confused since I am from C++ background, where this kind of things are valid.

Answer (score 0):

Function return values are not addressable:

https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignments

> Each left-hand side operand must be addressable, a map index expression, or (for = assignments only) the blank identifier. Operands may be parenthesized.

The following works, because the function return value is now assigned to the variable `v`, and `v` is addressable.

```
v := f1()
v.ID = 10
```

Comment: Does this actually have anything to do with addressability though? Nothing in that code is trying to take the address of anything (and none of the linked spec section appears to be relevant, as no address operators are used). It seems to be just that `f1().ID = 11` tries to modify the value of a field on a struct that's being discarded.

Comment: @Adrian: indirectly -- you can't modify a non-addressable value. Think about the result if you tried this using `reflect`.

Comment: @Adrian it does. This is similar to having a `m map[string]X` where `X` is a struct, and writing `m["a"].ID=1`

Comment: Right... I guess this answer is basically "correct but misleading" because it doesn't actually state that being addressable is a requirement for assignment; and should probably link to https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignments instead of address operators.

Comment: I changed the link.